# Pytorch model training images

Tags: pytorch

A couple of questions about the images used for training a model.

1. I am using Resnet50. There is something in creating the model about images being 224x224.I *think* this means the images are scaled to this size. Is this correct? If an image is 4000x3000 (iPhone), is the aspect ratio maintained so it ends up being 224x168? Should I resize all the images myself to 224x224?
2. Can the training image have multiple objects in it? For example, I am trying to train the model to recognize pickleballs. Can the input image have 1..30 balls in it, or does this confuse the training logic?

I have tried a variety of different sizing of the training images, but the model does not seem to train. I am trying to eliminate the input image format as the problem.